# Using PageBuilder as a template for SmartForm Content

Tags: content-management-system, ektron

I have some articles to publish and I have set up a smart form with all of the article content. I am using a PageBuilder page as a template and having the smart form use this template. I need the flexibility of the PageBuilder template with this content. This works well:
https://www.ektron.com/Blogs/eGandalf/Combining-Dynamic-Content-with-PageBuilder/

My issue is that now we need to have a mobile version of the article content.

My question is how do you have one smart form relate to two templates.This can be determined by device or URL.

For example,

```
if (desktop device)     
   use desktop template
else if (mobile device)
   use mobile template
```

or

```
if (http://domain.com/content/item)  
    use desktop template  
else if (http://domain.com/m/content/item)  
    use mobile template
```

I tried to do this with Quick Links, but the Quick Link is re written every time the page layout is updated. which is a major maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I can think of two ways to do this, so have added an answer for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mobile Templates**

You can specify a mobile version of your template. If the mobile template has dropzones with the same IDs as your desktop template, then the same widgets will be shown.

In this case, your URLs will be the same for both mobile and desktop, and Ektron will use device detection to decide which template to show.

[Ektron reference (particularly Setting Up a Mobile Template)](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v8.50/Reference/Mobile/Advanced/Content/Mobile_Devices/Mobile_Devices.htm)

Answer (score 0):

**Metadate to Smartform**

I've often used metadata to link to the smart form. The page layout can have a metadata link to the smart form, and then the widget needs to access the smart form via the metadata.

We usually set the metadata on both the desktop and mobile page layouts, to keep things consistent.

The pages will have different URLs in this scenario.